# Does kafka support wildcard topic matching and subscription on the broker side?

Tags: apache-kafka

Would like the consumer to subscribe to all topics I*

New topics starting with I may be created in the kafka cluster while the consumer is up and running already

Is there a way the kafka cluster/broker can auto subscribe the consumer to the new topics starting with I

Is the only way to do this kind of dynamic topic filtering/discovery/subscription is by the consumer calling metadata refresh every time interval and check for new topics added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The consumer is the one that subscribed and polls. The brokers do not push this metadata to the consumers.